# How do I pass the right UID in the same query, without it defaulting to Anonymous?

Tags: 7, views

I have this fantastic [view setup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/138068/39377) that lets me add endorsements to different items.

It works a little something like this, to get the UID of the endorser:

[image: how my view is rendered]

What I basically end up with is Advocate.Name = NULL and Advocate.Picture = NULL. I think internally Drupal is set up to pull these based on the UID (a guess based on below SQL), as it's not found it defaults to 0 - the anonymous user.

---

Here is the SQL code the view generates:

```
SELECT      users_field_data_field_endorser.name AS users_field_data_field_endorser_name, 
            users_field_data_field_endorser.uid AS users_field_data_field_endorser_uid, 
            users_field_data_field_endorser.picture AS users_field_data_field_endorser_picture, 
            users_field_data_field_endorser.mail AS users_field_data_field_endorser_mail, 
            node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 
            'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
            {node} node
LEFT JOIN   {field_data_field_tech_endorsement} field_data_field_tech_endorsement ON 
                node.nid = field_data_field_tech_endorsement.field_tech_endorsement_target_id AND
                (field_data_field_tech_endorsement.entity_type = 'node' AND 
                field_data_field_tech_endorsement.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN   {node} field_tech_endorsement_node ON 
                field_data_field_tech_endorsement.entity_id = field_tech_endorsement_node.nid
LEFT JOIN   {field_data_field_endorser} field_tech_endorsement_node__field_data_field_endorser ON 
                field_tech_endorsement_node.nid = field_tech_endorsement_node__field_data_field_endorser.entity_id AND (field_tech_endorsement_node__field_data_field_endorser.entity_type = 'node' AND field_tech_endorsement_node__field_data_field_endorser.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN   {users} users_field_data_field_endorser ON 
                field_tech_endorsement_node__field_data_field_endorser.field_endorser_target_id = users_field_data_field_endorser.uid
WHERE       (
                ( 
                    (field_tech_endorsement_node.nid = '13' ) 
                )AND
                (
                    ( 
                        (node.status = '1') 
                        AND 
                        (node.type IN  ('endorsement')) 
                    )
                )
            )
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

I have heard this can be an issue but copious googling doesn't seem to bring anything back (I probably don't know enough to search with the right terms).

So how do I pass the right UID to the view (Advocate View) from the NID of the other views?

Comment: I think this bug is related: https://www.drupal.org/node/2162635

Comment: Few things to try: 1. Make the relationship(s) compulsory (tick the 'Require this relationship' - the preferred way). 2. Add a filter criteria to the view that filters on uid > 0 (stopgap method that should work but does not address the underlying issue). Also re-asses why you need CER module.

Comment: @J.Reynolds 1) and 2) mean no content is displayed in the view. 3) To link entity references?