# Display a link to create new content when content missing (via Contextual Filters)?

Tags: 7, views

I'd like to give users the option to create new content when a certain contextual filter is missing on a panel.

e.g. I have my [reviews](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/137984/39377) on a panel. When a review is missing I'd like it to display a block/link to submit a new review.

However my only options are to hide the view, give a summary etc.

How do I do this?

I've found the option for '*No Results Behaviour*', but I can't hook into the contextual filter (and then use a relationship to grab a term name). I've also found this work around:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1895724

But I'm struggling to re-write the code to pull the term name out of the term id in the contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here I suppose you have added an argument in panel path. You can assign any `context` to your argument, eg `Node: Id`. It can be Term as well.

[image]

Assign any context to argument like :

[image]

Add a visibility rule if `Context exists` to your view and `not exists` to custom pane.

[image]

Comment: Sumit I don't really follow. I'm looking at this from the point of view of the ... View. Yes I have an argument from the panel, but I don't follow you after that. Did you read the [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/137984/39377) I linked?

Comment: So you're saying, "If the argument doesn't exist, skip calling the view", right? That _can_ work in some cases, but say you're checking, "has something been tagged with this term", then the term argument always exists, so this won't help. Do I understand that right?

Comment: Well thats correct @Letharion.. In the case you said `Views No Result` Behaviour will work. :)

Comment: @SumitMadan I may have been confusing this with another question I was looking at recently. Reading the question again it looks like this would be a good solution.

Comment: I don't think this works as I don't have a node id in that scope. I'm passing it as a value on a link from one view to the next. Does this still work?

Comment: @Pureferret Is the pointed to link also controlled by Panels? If so, it should work just fine.

Comment: So when I look on my context tab of the panel, I don't have any arguments set up there.Here's my config: http://imgur.com/a/hqw4q

Comment: Well It looks like you didn't setup argument in panel. Otherwise it should look between Basic and Access link under Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out, I turned on the PHP Filtering module, and inserted this as a Global text area, with `Text format = PHP Code`

```
<?php
    $view = views_get_current_view(); //get the current view
    $term =  taxonomy_term_load( $view->args[0] ); // the term id
    $term_name = taxonomy_term_title($term); //get the term id e.g. turn 123 = term_name
?>
<p>No comments exist for <?php print $term_name; ?>.</p>//print out the name
<p><a class="button" href="localhost/drupal/node/add/technology-comments?edit[field_technology][und][textfield]=<?php print $term_name; ?>">Add new comment</a> </p> //link to the add new page, pre-populating with term_name
<p></p>
```

Comment: Well if Its just about the Term Name in pane, I suggest you should create a ctool plugin rather than adding php code inside database.

Comment: Thanks, @SumitMadan I'll look into it. [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/33336/39377) looks like a good place to start?