# Master Detail page for taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I'm essentially trying to recreate the [results](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/137840/39377) of this question, but using taxonomy terms instead of nodes.

I have my master view (a list of taxonomy terms from a vocab') `item-view`, which has the term ID (TID) and I've re-written it to link to the other view `item-details/[tid]`.

On the detail view I have a contextual filter of Taxonomy term: Term ID (to match the field in the other view) and my `Argument Input` settings match those in the previous [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/137840/39377) (namely: 'From Panel Argument' for the list box 'Taxonomy term: Term ID source', then 'First' from Panel argument.)

But on the page (`item-page`) that holds both views in separate columns, it just links through to the detail view, at `item-details/[tid]`, opening the url in the browser rather than enacting that special drupal magic that makes it appear in the right hand column.

Does this not work with Terms and TIDs? Or have I missed something?

Comment: What are the urls/paths for your two pages? The one with and without terms?

Comment: @Letharion The Master page is at `item-view` and the links of there point to `item-details/[tid]`, the detail view is at `item-details/[tid]` for each item.

Answer (score 2):

> The Master page is at item-view and the links of there point to
>   item-details/[tid], the detail view is at item-details/[tid] for each
>   item.

In reality the links on the master page shouldn't link *to* the details view, but just to the current page with `/[tid]` appended.

Comment: And as to the previous answer (nodes), there you added the panel content as a view (a slight oversight). Better is to add it as a view pane (which you already set up), and then you do not have to send it the argument, it will just pick it up on the content pane itself, so one less configuration to do.